# Google Autocomplete API for use with MKMapKit

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, mkmapview, mapkit

The app that I am currently working on has to do this kind of features.

1.User input "Address"  and then there will be autocomplete (suggestion for that address) 
2. After user hits search button . The MKMapkit has to bring user to that 'Address' and zoom region to that

I can do the #1 by using Google Autocomplete API and using this module [TRAutocompleteView](http://github.com/TarasRoshko/TRAutocompleteView)

Now ,I'm trying to figure to do #2 feature. I thought I can use Address result from google API to convert into lat,long by CLPlacemark but I tested the concept with this module which use CLPlacemark to convert address string 
[SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete](https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete)

I found out that 20-30% of the address string can't be convert using CLPlacemark .It happes to be "Location not found" .And that happens mostly when you search in foreign language (I tried Thai language "

Are any other option for me implement these 2 features ? My app will be like YELP which has to search some result within specific region . Or can I use another way to do the address suggestion beside Google Autocomplete API ?

Changing MapKit to Google Map SDK can be one of the solution.But I want that to be last choice because it might be expensive if I exceed the daily limit

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a FYI, it is against the Google Terms of Service to use the Google Places Autocomplete with a non Google Map.

Comment: Thanks for the information ,I end up using MKLocalSearch from Apple instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is an obvious side effect of getting an address from Google and then asking Apple's API to turn those addresses into coordinates. Google will give you an address based on the data it has and the formatting style it wants, these will not always directly translate into Apple's data and format. If you want it to be properly reliable you need to stick with one set of services, Google or Apple, or a third party. It might be expensive if you exceed the daily limit but wouldn't that mean you're selling lots of copies of your app and such is the cost of doing business.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. Anyway, the place that I want to get in my autocomplete field can be less detailed than the autocomplete api from google. Just name of the city, country should be fine. Just like the location bar in YELP or Foursquare app. Any suggestion ? . Maybe just MKLocalSearch should be fine. I am trying to implement it now.